# installation graphviz, no module named graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, random-forest, decision-tree

I been trying to install graphviz and connect with python to graph some nodes for decision trees. I had read a lot of threads with the same problem as me but i perform much of the solutions but i still cannot perform my decision trees :(

I am not a programmer, i am just an simple economist which is trying to learn machine learning models, so for me is difficult to read much of the solutions provided in other threads.

I already could `conda install -c anaconda graphviz` in my cmd and `conda install -c anaconda pydot` and installation was completed. (I also download the rar package from GraphViz page)

Then i try to import graphviz, but python shows me the following error `No module named 'graphviz'`.

So then i try to add to my environment a new path with the following cd `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` but i continue to having the same problem.

I am trying to run the following script in my spyder codes but without any succed

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

import pydot
from IPython.display import Image, display
# import graphviz as gv

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, DecisionTreeClassifier, 
export_graphviz
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier, 
BaggingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,confusion_matrix, 
classification_report

# This function creates images of tree models using pydot
def print_tree(estimator, features, class_names=None, filled=True):
   tree = estimator
   names = features
   color = filled
   classn = class_names

   dot_data = StringIO()
   export_graphviz(estimator, out_file=dot_data, feature_names=features, 
   class_names=classn, filled=filled)
   graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
   return(graph)

hitter = 
pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ldresl\\Documents\\Chapter8\\Hitters.csv',sep=';')

hitter = hitter.dropna()

#Llamo una nueva matriz
X = hitter[['Years','Hits']].as_matrix()
y = np.log(hitter.Salary.as_matrix())

 #Se corre todo el codigo junto
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(11,4))
ax1.hist(hitter.Salary.as_matrix())
ax1.set_xlabel('Salary')
ax2.hist(y)
ax2.set_xlabel('Log(Salary)');

# Corro la regresion de la decision tree (NOTAR QUE NO ES RANDOM FOREST!!!)
regr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=3)
regr.fit(X, y)

graph, = print_tree(regr, features=['Years', 'Hits'])
Image(graph.create_png())
```

but whenever i try to run the last two lines throws me the following error `[WinError 2] "dot.exe" not found in path.`. Also if i write `import graphviz as gv` doesnt found it.

Sorry for my english :( i am learning :).

Comment: This means that graphviz was not installed as expected. Probably you are executing your python script in an environment that is not the same that conda installed graphviz into. There's a guide about this topic in the Anaconda documentation. https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#conda-reports-that-a-package-is-installed-but-it-appears-not-to-be

Answer (score 10):

There exists now a python-graphviz package at Anaconda.org which contains the Python interface for the graphviz tool. Simply install it with:

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation) for more info.

Comment: This "conda install python-graphviz" worked for me in Mac-Intel, in VSCode, with Anaconda Navigator, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Below command worked for me in windows 10, Anaconda version 4.8.3 :

```
conda install -c anaconda python-graphviz
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve the problem is:

source activate anaconda
pip install pydot
pip install pydotplus
pip install pydot-ng

Then you download and install Graphviz according to your OS type:

http://www.graphviz.org/download/

Check my previous answer for more information:
[Python RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683390/python-runtimeerror-failed-to-import-pydot/39842355#39842355)

Answer (score 0):

conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/garylschultz pygraphviz